# Find the Nth row from data.table using two or more values in a row

Tags: r, data.table

I have a large data set and would like to find the row where multiple columns equal a specific value.

```
#Example##
Constants <- data.frame(Functional_Class_Code=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19),
F_Code=c(1,3,0,0,0,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,7),
Urban_Rural=c("R","R","0","0","0","R","R","R","R","0","U ","U ","0","U ","0","U ","U ","U ","U "),
g=c(0.0127,0.0202,0,0,0,0.0153,0.0156,0.0161,0.0185,0,0.0087,0.0129,0,0.0118,0,0.0112,0.0154,0.0154,0.0229))

##find the row where...
UR = "R"
FC = 5

##I tried this
y<-c(Urban_Rural=UR, F_Code=FC)
Constants[1,]==y
```

I know that row 7 contains this combination of Urban_Rural = 5 && F_Code = 5

Comment: do you need `library(data.table); setDT(Constants)[Urban_Rural == UR & F_Code == FC]`

Comment: In data.table, there's standard syntax for this. Use `list` instead of `c` so that `5` is not coerced into string `"5"` and join with the `on=` argument. See `?data.table` for the exact syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Constants <- data.frame(Functional_Class_Code=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19),
                        F_Code=c(1,3,0,0,0,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,0,3,0,4,5,6,7),
                        Urban_Rural=trimws(c("R","R","0","0","0","R","R","R","R","0","U ","U ","0","U ","0","U ","U ","U ","U ")),
                        g=c(0.0127,0.0202,0,0,0,0.0153,0.0156,0.0161,0.0185,0,0.0087,0.0129,0,0.0118,0,0.0112,0.0154,0.0154,0.0229))

y <- which(Constants$Urban_Rural == "R" & Constants$F_Code == 5)

Constants[y,]
  Functional_Class_Code F_Code Urban_Rural      g
7                     7      5           R 0.0156
```

Comment: Dij - Thank you! I originally tested with "which" but didn't assign it to a variable which I think was my shortcoming. You are awesome, sir. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: You're welcome! You can actually skip that step if you just call: `Constants[Constants$Urban_Rural == "R" & Constants$F_Code == 5, ]`

Comment: I'm actually running into an issue with anything over row 9 in the data.frame. For instance, using the Constants data.frame above, this call works and returns row 9:

UR = "R"
FC = 7
TheRow = which(Constants$Urban_Rural == UR & Constants$F_Code == FC)

But this one does not (it's on row 12) - shows 'integer(0)' :
UR = "U"
FC = 2
TheRow = which(Constants$Urban_Rural == UR & Constants$F_Code == FC)

Comment: Updated:: I'm actually running into an issue with anything over row 9 in the data.frame. For instance, using the Constants data.frame above, UR = "R" and FC = 7, works and returns row 9. However, UR = "U" and FC = 2, does NOT work, but should return row 12. Any combination that returns a row greater than 9 shows 'integer(0)' for some reason

Comment: @EricW the issue you are experiencing is actually because there is irregular white-space smattered around the characters in the `Urban_Rural` column. If you don't need these spaces, (i.e., if `"U"` means the same thing as `"U "`), then before filtering or indexing as above you should call: `Constants$Urban_Rural <- trimws(Constants$Urban_Rural)`

Answer (score 0):

As the OP asked a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Constants)[Urban_Rural == UR & F_Code == FC]
#. Functional_Class_Code F_Code Urban_Rural      g
#1:                     7      5           R 0.0156
```